# Mechanism for chloromethylation of Salicylaldehyde

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Reaction mechanism for following reaction :

Salicylaldehyde + formaldehyde +con. HCl $\ce{->}$ 5-(Chloromethyl)salicylaldehyde

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a homework question thus you must show some effort in the question since you are new please visit [Homework Policy](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/142#142) for more info .

So now on the answer,

this is a really simple and a nice case of Friedel-Crafts Alkylation . the mechanism go as follow :

1. The Oxygen atom on formaldehyde gets protonated, leaving a carbcation.
2. This carbcation gets added to the Salicylaldehyde by EAS (Electrophilic aromatic substitution).
3. The alchol so formed gets dehydrated to again get a carbcation which finally gets attacked by $\ce{Cl-}$ to form the final product .

The mechanism scheme is as follow :
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: There  is  a  formation  of  carbocation  but  not  carbanion

Comment: Ohh... sorry I wanted to write carbcation but wrote carbanion by mistake I will correct it